# Euler equations in 3D

Tags: calculus

How can I find the Euler equations for compressible mediums and 3 dimensional problems? Our textbook only provides the following $$\rho(\frac{\delta u}{\delta t}+u\frac{\delta u}{\delta x}+v \frac{\delta u}{\delta y})=-\nabla p + \rho b $$
The left hand side inside the brackets is just the fluid acceleration. So this equation is the Euler equation for two dimensional incompressible flow. What do I have to do or where do I have to look to find out how the 3D and compressible one works? Google didn't help me that much and as I said my textbook is only working in the 2D scope. Any hint or help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In three dimensions the Euler equations are written as,

$$ \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} + (\vec{v} \cdot \nabla) \vec{v} = -\frac{1}{\rho} \nabla p, $$

with the continuity equation,

$$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t } + \nabla \cdot ( \rho \vec{v} ) = 0. $$

If the fluid is incompressible this second equation becomes $\nabla \cdot \vec{v} = 0 $.